# What is this test pattern used for? (Computer vision, camera distortion mapping)

Tags: camera

[image]

I came across a test pattern a few years back in a robotics laboratory that I remember being told was some sort of test pattern to train cameras for robotic vision.  It was like some sort of checkerboard pattern but it was not a uniform pattern. 
The image is my best rendition of it.  Does anyone know what this type of pattern is called and what its use is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [fiducial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiduciary_marker)?

[image: alt text a]
[image: alt text b]

A [coded aperture](http://astrophysics.gsfc.nasa.gov/cai/coded_intr.html) for [computational photography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_photography)?

[image]

A [2D barcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode#Matrix_.282D.29_barcodes) or [bokode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokode)?

[image]

Comment: ah figured out what it was, but that coded aperture is pretty interesting, glad you posted that.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that it is a "non-repeating pattern" used to establish register between two cameras.

Answer (score 1):

Ok turns out it was a [camera calibration pattern](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/documentation/usercalibration.htm).

edit: NM my mistake

Comment: Which one matches the image you supplied?

Comment: Agree with W5VO... most of the pictures on that page look like sheets of dots, not the pixelated creature in your post.

Comment: Yeah, Google Image Search just finds regular patterns of dots or checkerboards: http://google.com/images?q=camera+calibration+pattern  It's probably a fiducial marker.